# How to use LibSVMsharp with x64 libSVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, libsvm, libsvmsharp

i have downloaded LibSVMsharp  via nugget package.

I have visual studio 2013 and using .net 4.5.2 wpf application

It works in x86 however i want to use x64 libsvm

So i followed the instructions to built my own x64 libsvm

I did it successfully but i am getting error

**How can i solve this problem?**

Here how i compiled x64 libsvm.dll below

[image]

Here the error i get when i use x64 libsvm in my application via LibSVMsharp  wrapper

[image]